# passport Google auth in Node to get the refreshToken

Tags: node.js, passport.js

I trying to get refreshToken because the accessToken have some minutes per use.
At code I can't to get. What's my error?

```
import * as passport from "passport";
import { Strategy as GoogleStrategy } from "passport-google-oauth20";
...
passport.use(
      new GoogleStrategy(
        {
          clientID: this.configService.get("GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID"),
          clientSecret: this.configService.get("GOOGLE_SECRET"),
          callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/schedule/google/callback",
          scope: [
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events",
            "profile",
            "email",
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar",
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile",
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
          ],
          accessType: "offline",
          prompt: "consent",
          // passReqToCallback: true
        },
        function (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
          console.log(refreshToken);
          return done(null, accessToken);
        }
      )
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

Passing scope during strategy creation is not valid. See [Passport Google Oauth20 Doc](https://www.passportjs.org/packages/passport-google-oauth20/).

Do not pass scope, access type and prompt during strategy creation instead pass during authenticate requests.

You can do like this:

Step 1: Configure strategy

```js
passport.use(
      new GoogleStrategy(
        {
          clientID: this.configService.get("GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID"),
          clientSecret: this.configService.get("GOOGLE_SECRET"),
          callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/schedule/google/callback",
        },
        function (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
          console.log(refreshToken);
          return done(null, {
                    profile,
                    accessToken,
                    refreshToken
                });
        }
      )
    );
```

Step 2: Authenticate Request with scope, accessType and prompt during this step

```js
app.get('/auth/google',
  passport.authenticate('google',
  { 
    scope: ['profile', 'email'],
    accessType: 'offline',
    prompt: 'consent',
  }
));
```

Comment: In accessType I get it:
`((...args: any[]) => any)): any', generated the following error.
     Object literal can only specify known properties and 'accessType' does not exist in type 'AuthenticateOptions'.`


`
"passport-google-oauth20": "^2.0.0",
"passport": "^0.6.0",
`

Comment: I did not get you, in which step you are getting this issue?

Comment: Step 2, when gonna put 'accessType' value

Comment: Resolved using this: https://linuxamination.blogspot.com/2022/09/google-api-generate-access-token-and.html